# Given a commutative C* algebra, can we tell if it is a function ring of some manifold to $\mathbb{R}$(or $\mathbb{C}$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a (unital) commutative C* algebra $A$, we know that $A$ must corresponding to a (compact)locally compact Hausdorff space, is there a way to tell if it is isomorphic to some ring of continuous function from a manifold to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of spectral triples, but the theorem you are looking for is surely the very famous and celebrated reconstruction theorem of Connes.

https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2088